# WAS 6 to WAS 7 migration Java EE code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rad

After I auto migrated my Java EE project from WAS6 to WAS7 using iRAD migration tool I am facing many errors.
These errors seem vague mostly in JSP pages.
I've used JDK 1.5 now (previously 1.4)

Errors:

- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete EnumBody
- The method `convertEnum()` in the type `BeanUtil` is not applicable for the arguments (`AgreeState`)
- Syntax error on token "`catch`", invalid `AnnotationName`

The source code is perfectly fine. Am I missing on some other configuration?

Comment: I have faced that kind of error too. It seems okay.

Comment: Could you post the relevant pieces of code?

Comment: @adarshr: Thanks 4 your concern. But it works, we can simply ignore those JSP errors.